# selector/method name as string argument

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

So this code works (sends the method name as a string to the receiving method)

```
[self.Client sendDigitalJoinAndReleaseByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",_cmd]];
```

However since ios 6 (I think) I now get a warning

> Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type SEL

Is there even a format specifier for SEL?
What is the proper way to do this (so that there is no warning)?

Comment: I notice that there's a runtime function: `const char* sel_getName(SEL aSelector)`.  I haven't used it....

Comment: Why not pass `SEL` rather than formatting it to a string?

Comment: what is _cmd ? And what is the type of that function argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)` and print the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could use NSStringFromSelector:

```
[self.Client sendDigitalJoinAndReleaseByName:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
```

Comment: Note that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` doesn't do quite the same thing: it returns the (nicely formatted) name of *this function*, not that of any arbitrary function.

Comment: @bdesham Good idea pointing that out, the only reason I included it was to basically point out that it existed, but the way I worded it made it sound like I was comparing the two. Removing.